# Google Cloud Run - Using GitHub for continuous deployment : Your build failed to run: generic::invalid_argument: invalid build: invalid image name

Tags: github, deployment, cloud

After creating a successful build using gbuild I wanted to start the continues deployment function but on trigger it failed instantly with the name: Your build failed to run: generic::invalid_argument: invalid build: invalid image name

The answer is: don't use capital letters in your GitHub Repository Name as Google Cloud Run doesn't seem to like it and it causes that very vague error message

(Posting it here as a question/answer as it took my hours to figure out)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share this answer. I'm surprised there aren't more people who run into this issue

Answer (score 9):

The answer is: don't use capital letters in your GitHub Repository Name as Google Cloud Run doesn't seem to like it and it causes that very vague error message

Answer (score 2):

It indeed seems to be an issue with capital letters in the repo name. You can circumvent this issue by selecting the 'Mirror GitHub repository using Cloud Source Repositories' option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the the repo name parameter with `$` and the repo name contains capital letters, the build fails. This issue is related to the gcr image creation as the build starts. When I replaced the parameterized repo name with a lower case letters for the container name, instead of the capitalized repo name, for the gcr image location, my build went through.

Comment: Would be awesome if you [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71082780/5411817) to give an example of the before & after line of code.